# How can I iterate over a Pandas DataFrame and run a function over them

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, loops

I have my CSV data saved as a dataframe and I want to take the values of a row then use them in a function. I'll try to show what I am looking for. I have tried sorting by amounts but I can figure out how to separate out the data after that step. I am new to Pandas and I would appreciate any helpful and problem-relevant feedback.

UPDATE: If you suggest using .apply on the dataframe, could you show me a good way of applying a complex function. The Pandas documentation only shows simple functions which I don't find useful given the contex.

Here is the df

```
            Date   Amount
0     12/27/2019      NaN
1     12/27/2019   -14.00
2     12/27/2019   -15.27
3     12/30/2019    -1.00
4     12/30/2019   -35.01
5     12/30/2019    -9.99
6     01/02/2020    -7.57
7     01/03/2020  1225.36
8     01/03/2020   -40.00
9     01/03/2020   -59.90
10    01/03/2020    -9.52
11    01/06/2020   100.00
12    01/06/2020    -6.41
13    01/06/2020   -31.07
14    01/06/2020    -2.50
15    01/06/2020    -7.46
16    01/06/2020   -18.98
17    01/06/2020    -1.25
18    01/06/2020    -2.50
19    01/06/2020    -1.25
20    01/06/2020  -170.94
21    01/06/2020  -150.00
22    01/07/2020   -20.00
23    01/07/2020   -18.19
24    01/07/2020    -4.00
25    01/08/2020    -1.85
26    01/08/2020    -1.10
27    01/09/2020   -21.00
28    01/09/2020   -31.00
29    01/09/2020    -7.13
30    01/10/2020   -10.00
31    01/10/2020    -1.75
32    01/10/2020  -125.00
33    01/13/2020   -10.60
34    01/13/2020    -2.50
35    01/13/2020    -7.00
36    01/13/2020   -46.32
37    01/13/2020    -1.25
38    01/13/2020   -39.04
39    01/13/2020    -9.46
40    01/13/2020  -179.00
41    01/13/2020  -140.00
42    01/15/2020  -150.04
```

I want to take the amount value from a row, then look for a matching amount value. Once a matching value is found I want to run a timedelta between the two rows with a matching value.

Thus far, every time I have tried a conditional statement of some sort I get an error. Does anyone have any ideas how I might be able to accomplish this task?

Here is a bit of code I have started with.

```py
amount_1 = df.loc[1, 'Amount']
amount_2 = df.loc[2, 'Amount']
print(amount_1, amount_2)

date_1 = df.loc[2, 'Date'] #skipping the first row.
x = 2
x += 1
date_2 = df.loc[x, 'Date']


## Not real code, but a logical flow I am aiming for

if amount_2 == amount_1:
   timed = date_2 - date_1
   print(timed, amount_2)

elif amount_2 != amount_1:
  # go to the next row and check
```

Comment: Can’t you just group by amounts? They you will have same amounts with different dates to which you can find delta.

Comment: You'll need to create the function that you want and then pass it into  .apply() function in pandas.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I know how to sort by amount but I don't know how to pull the information I need out of the sorted format.

Comment: @Geom I'll take a look at that, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use something like that:

```
distinct_values = df["Amount"].unique()  # Select all distinct values

for value_unique in distinct_values:  # for each distinct value
    temp_df = df.loc[df["Amount"] == value_unique]  # find rows of that value

    # You could iterate over that temp df to do your timedelta operations...
```

Comment: would you suggest a while statement to iterate?